# How do i do to connect my electron app with reactjs build folder?so i want to run the app in any PC

Tags: reactjs, node.js, electron

I tried to connect my [tag:electron application] with react in development mode it runs exactly as i expected, and it accepts to build an .exe file. But when a run that .exe file in another PC, it does run correctely,  it gives me a blank screen.

At my first thoughts i hoped that i might first run [tag:npm run build] to create the build folder the after  i will connect my electron app with the react app through the build folder. But after making the react build folder it still gives me [tag:blank screen] when i run my electron app.
The bellow is my electron code

```
const electron = require('electron');
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url')
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

let win;

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        minWidth: 1000,
        width: 1000,
        height: 600,
        minHeight: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            devTools: true
        }
    });

    const startUrl = url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    })

    // win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
    win.loadFile(startUrl);
    win.setMenu(null)
    // win.webContents.openDevTools();

    win.on('close', function () {
        win = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    app.quit();
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (win == null) {
        createWindow();
    }
})
```

And this is my files structure

I want to run my .exe application in any PC, not only in development mode in my pc. so i would like to connect it with react build folder, but any time i do it it gives me a blank screen

Could anyone help me how to do it?